# Как считать byte[] с FileStream поблочно?

Tags: c#, filestream

Пытаюсь считать с `FileStream` поблочно данные. Вроде как всё выглядит складно, но в результате я получаю 5 записей одного и того же массива (`byte[]`) в `tmp`.

Судя по всему, я неправильно понимаю логику работы считывания с данного потока. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    List<byte[]> tmp = new List<byte[]>();
    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        tmp.Add(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы в C# ссылочный тип. Так что у Вас добавляется 5 ссылок на один и тот же массив, который перезаполняется внутри цикла. И после завершения цикла Вы имеете в списке 5 ссылок на один и тот же массив с последним полученным значением. Перенесите чтение и создание массива внутрь цикла:

```
    while (true)
    {
        var buffer=new int[size];
        read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (read>0)
            tmp.Add(buffer);
        else
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается всё было просто )